# Zooming an UIView without losing detail

Tags: ios, uiview

Let's say I have a complex `UIView`, which is initially on the screen with quite small frame, let's say 80x80.

One of its subviews is an `UIImageView` displaying an image whose actual resolution is 1024x1024.

When the user tap the `UIView` i want the view to zoom in almost full screen so that the user can better see the image.

I know already how to scale a `UIView` to zoom in, my question is the following.

What's the best way to zoom in this view without pixellating the image?

I thought of these options:

1. I can actually set the frame of the `UIView` to the full screen size, and normally scale it down, so I'm sure that when it's zoomed in, it will be perfectly detailed. This solution anyway have a strong performance issue, cause moving around many of these scaled down views, will be quite an hit on the CPU/GPU.
2. I can do it just as I described, so small frame and scale > 1 to zoom in, but in this case will the image be displayed without pixellating?
3. I can actually set the frame to redisplay the view at the big/small size. In this case the detail will be good, but I have a performance hit here too, because my `UIView` have around 15 subviews that need complex calculation to relayout, so it's not so "fast" to set the frame.

Which is the best solution? Or do anybody have any other better solution?

Comment: Try using `UIScrollView` class for zoom functionality.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not answering my question. If I should use a scrollview (which in my case is not possible cause I should have too many of them) setting the frame of my view to 80x80 and zooming in is it not going to pixellate?

Comment: Check out this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you just have thumbnail representations that are `80x80`, and when the user taps on any thumbnail, you transition from your current view containing all the thumbnails to a  `new view` with the `+transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:` method and simply display a UIImageView with the full resolution image loaded into that new view :)

Comment: I understand your solution, but the view is not a simple image, it's a very complex view with around 20 subviews, with transparency and so over. Allocating one more when zooming is not possible, cause the creation and display process takes almost 4 second on an iPhone4. Thanks anyway for your suggestion.

Comment: You are most likely complicating things. Show us a screenshot of what youre doing, because from what you posted as a question, my solution would suffice.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot provide a screen, cause my work is under NDA for my customer. My view has around 20 subviews, each of this change its frame when the view bounds change, because they need to position according to some formulas, and not just in the center. So if I change the frame of the view, the effect takes at least 4 sec on an iPhone4 to display. Mostly because some of this subview are dinamically drawed, some with OpenGL texturing. So to be short, changing the frame or allocating a new one is not an option for me.

Comment: @Axy I've written an answer based on how things should initially be done. If something is taking 4 seconds to load as you described, there's probably a better way to do it. Based on the abstract information you've provided, I cannot help you. Goodluck.

Comment: I mostly refactored my code, anyway I'm accepting your answer because it's the only one ;) and because it's probably the most I can get without giving enough details. Thanks

Comment: @Axy to accept this answer, simply click the tick button on the left hand side of my post :)